# How can I mirror some website on my own website URL?

Tags: web, server, routes, mirror

I have some website e.g.(examle.com) I want that website mirrored on my own URL (mywebsite.com) so that if user hit url(mywebsite.com/url*) it give mirror results of similar url of origional site(example.com/url*)

Comment: do you mean mirrored as in literally reversed left to right? or just the same site? And if you do mean just the same site, is there any reason you can't just point your domain to the other domain? Or do you need to have it on a separate server for some reason?

Comment: I actually want to log in and create a session on the website from my server and don't want to share credentials with my team so if there is any way that my session is created on the website server and when someone access it through my website it gives the results from my site.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by "results" what results are you trying to hide? Depending on what it is you are trying to hyde, You will have to do some coding and set permissions on the site itself so they cannot see what you do not want them to see. What is the site written in??

Comment: There is a website which require login password. I want to open that website somewhere on server with my login pass and let my team access that portal through ip address of that server.